# How to open Mainactivity after login success with PHP massage?

Tags: php, android, authentication

I am trying to open Mainactivity after login success

```
protected void onPostExecute(JSONObject result) {
    try {
        if (result != null) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),result.getString("message"),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Unable to retrieve any data from server", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
}
```

"message" from PHP: "Successfully logged in" and "Incorrect details"

If i change:

```
protected void onPostExecute(JSONObject result) {
    try {
        if (result != null) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), result.getString("message"), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class);
            getApplicationContext().startActivity(i);
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Unable to retrieve any data from server", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

When both logged in successfully or failed, it enter MainActivity
Somebody help me

Comment: Check out this [project](https://github.com/NeilSayok/Car-Locator-System) on github. It also uses login and signup in both the apps.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your code, you will enter MainActivity when the result object is not null. You should add more conditions for entering MainActivity, like:

```
if (result != null && result.getString("result").equals("success"))
```

Comment: Sorry mate, by mistake I modified your answer instead of me. Reverting.

Answer (score 0):

You are just checking if `result` is null or not. You should check for the exact status of login by modifying your code something like this.

```
if (result != null && result.optString("message", "failed").equals("Successfully logged in"))
```

Using `optString` will do good even if the value for "message" is null.

**NOTE:** You can modify the code based on your JSON structure.

Answer (score 0):

Replace your if condition with below condition.

```
  if (result != null && result.getString("message").contains("Successfully logged in"))
```

Answer (score -1):

```
protected void onPostExecute(JSONObject result) {
        try {
            if (result.length() != 0) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), result.getString("message"), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class);
                      startActivity(i);

            } else {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Unable to retrieve any data from server", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```